# Open %% File name

Tags: cmd

How can I open a file in cmd were the name not complete from is?

"C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore\ **2013-12-19 18.20.00.911** Formal.Assessment (Recent).WinSAT.xml"

I will open this file without the time information **"%Formal.Assessment (Recent).WinSAT.xml%"**

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Is there only one file or more? If more, which one do you want to open?

Comment: Only **one file** without the time "Formal.Assessment (Recent).WinSAT.xml"

Comment: If there is only one file, where is the problem? Do you have the file without the time part and want to open with it? Do you have the file/s with the time part and want to open as if timepart is not present? Sorry, but i don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, the original file is "2013-12-19 18.20.00.911 Formal.Assessment (Recent).WinSAT.xml" I will open this file on every computer with a command but the time is different from this file.

Comment: Your english is not worse than mine. So, summarizing, you have only one file in the folder with the `Formal.Assessment ....` filename, prefixed with an unknown datetime part. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be used from command line, replace double percent signs `%%` with a single percent `%`

Enumerate the files in folder that match the indicated pattern and use start command to, well, start the file with the associated application. Adapt as needed.

```
for %%f in ("C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore\*Formal.Assessment (Recent).WinSat.xml") do start "" "%%~ff"
```